# apt upgrade error 16.04 / hang on "sync" task, after cpio build of initramfs, from postinst.d

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

When upgrading (apt-get upgrade) on 16.04 (ubuntu-mate) I get a hang (left from 9:50am til 16:00 or thereabouts)

I tracked down as far as the call to `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools` and added a `-v` option, the last relevant lines on the terminal when re-running `apt-get upgrade` are as follows:

```
...
Adding binary /bin/date
Adding binary /sbin/hwclock
Adding binary /sbin/dumpe2fs
Calling hook dmsetup
Calling hook reiserfsprogs
Building cpio /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-24-generic.new initramfs

^CFailed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic is not configured yet.
```

Checking with `ps fax` before the interrupt, I get this tree - indicating a hang on `sync` task (Running `dpkg --configure -a` and `apt-get upgrade` take me both to the same state)

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
 \_ dpkg --configure -a
     \_ /usr/bin/perl /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic.postinst configure
     \_ run-parts --verbose --exit-on-error --arg=4.4.0-24-generic --arg=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic /etc/kernel/postinst.d
         \_ /bin/sh -e /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
             \_ /bin/sh /usr/sbin/update-initramfs -v -c -t -k 4.4.0-24-generic -b /boot
                 \_ sync
```

I tried moving the resulting initramfs img file in `/boot` so a new one would be created - a new one is indeed created, hang still occurs on `sync`

Answer (score 1):

If

```
sudo dmsetup mknodes
```

does not fix it:

perhaps you have some kind of strange mount locking up-
for example stale cifs...

So try to unmount everything that's perhaps not healthy. 
If for example umount of CIFS/SMB fails, then force it

```
umount -a -t cifs -l
```